# XCopy or Copy command not working in Start-Commit hook script of SVN

Tags: svn, batch-file, automation

Allow me to explain my purpose behind this problem. I created a batch file wherein I compare my development database to our server database, the result is an sql file. I want the sql file to be added to my version control before I commit my changes. The problem is when I hook up my script to "copy" the sql file to the working copy it was not copied.

Here is the simple script: I know that hook script cannot contain environment variable because of security purpose thus I use absolute path.

```
"C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe" "C:\Users\user\Documents\SQL Delta\*.sql" /Y "C:\Users\princessm\Documents\user\main\Materials Management\scripts\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks clean. you are actually trying to copy from user `user` directory to another user `princessm` directory.

Can you check, do you have access to that directory. If yes please post the error you are getting for further analysis.

Comment: actually the "user" and "princessm" is actually the users on my local pc.